# Error installing fasttext on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: python, fasttext

i'm trying to install the latest git fasttext code (Jan 25, 2022), and getting error

- Using the latest Version : https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
- Ubuntu 21.04
- gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
- g++ -v
- Python 3.9 (-dev also installed)
- virtualenv

Thank You
Mo

```
Ubuntu 21.04

Install Method
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ pip install .

$gcc --version
- gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
- Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
- This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
- warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-10-gDeRY6/gcc-10-10.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-10-gDeRY6/gcc-10-10.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.3.0 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1)

(.projectvenv) root@kbase:/home/projects/fastText# pip install . --verbose

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-FZ7wim/python3.9-3.9.5=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-FZ7wim/python3.9-3.9.5=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.o -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden
    python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc: In lambda function:
    python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc:346:35: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int32_t’ {aka ‘int’} and ‘std::vector<long int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
      346 |             for (int32_t i = 0; i < vocab_freq.size(); i++) {
          |                                 ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc: In lambda function:
    python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc:360:35: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int32_t’ {aka ‘int’} and ‘std::vector<long int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
      360 |             for (int32_t i = 0; i < labels_freq.size(); i++) {
          |                                 ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    Running setup.py install for fasttext ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-b_xalqqz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-b_xalqqz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5c2xoor2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/include/site/python3.9/fasttext Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 848, in install
    success = install_legacy(
  File "/home/projects/projecta12/.projecta12venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/legacy.py", line 86, in install
    raise LegacyInstallFailure
pip._internal.operations.install.legacy.LegacyInstallFailure
```

Comment: It looks like cc1plus was killed by the [OOM killer](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360052914574-What-Is-the-OOM-Killer-). Try closing other programs or adding more memory.

Comment: The text / the file README.md says `you will need ...  Python version 2.7 or >=3.4`

Comment: @NathanMills you are right , Thank You